# Trying to show how many rows we have in the database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database of airfield cards and would like to show how many of them we have, on the first page of the site.  I have looked into it, and found this on the web, but when I add it to my site, I get the dreaded blank screen error, so there's obviously something not right in the code.

I am simply trying to return (how many) cards there are in the database, then display it as a number to the user.  Like this...

Card number = 380

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `users` WHERE 
visible='0'");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$count = $row['count'];
```

Comment: **Please**, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799), and `mysql_*` functions have been officially removed in PHP 7. Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and use either `PDO` or `mysqli_*`. If you can't decide, [this article will help to choose your best option](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: Your query seems fine to me. Are you including the `DB` connection file and enable errors by `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`. to check for errors.

Comment: Connecting to the DB OK. But haven't got the errors on.